# Yield values from generator from async functions without awaiting

Tags: dart, stream, generator, dart-async

I need to run many async functions concurrently and yield the results as they complete, order doesn't matter.

Here is what i have in a simplified example, of course this does not work right because it's waiting for every response before moving to the next request.

```
 Stream<String> stringGenerator(List<http.Request> requests) async* {
    final httpClient = http.Client();
    for (var req in requests) {
      final response = await httpClient.send(req);
      yield response.headers['example'];
    }
  }
```

Comment: Did you find a solution without using StreamController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try and see if this is working for you?

```
Stream<String> stringGenerator(List<http.Request> requests) {
  final controller = StreamController<String>();
  final httpClient = http.Client();

  Future.wait(requests.map((req) => httpClient
          .send(req)
          .then((response) => controller.add(response.headers['example']!))))
      .whenComplete(() => controller.close());

  return controller.stream;
}
```

More correct would be this, since we don't want to generate events before we are listening for them according to the documentation for `StreamController`. It is really not an issue for internal usage since `StreamController` does buffer events until a listener are subscribed:

```
Stream<String> stringGenerator(List<http.Request> requests) {
  final controller = StreamController<String>();
  
  controller.onListen = () {
    final httpClient = http.Client();

    Future.wait(requests.map((req) => httpClient
        .send(req)
        .then((response) => controller.add(response.headers['example']!))))
        .whenComplete(() => controller.close());
  };

  return controller.stream;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A generalized alternative to @julemand101's solution which works for any kind of futures:

```dart
Stream<T> fromFutures<T>(Iterable<Future<T>> futures) {
  var pending = 0;
  var controller = Controller<T>();
  for (var future in futures) {
    pending++;
    future.then((v) {
      controller.add(v);
      if (--pending == 0) controller.close();
    }, onError: (e, s) {
      controller.addError(e, s);
      if (--pending == 0) controller.close();
    });
  }
  return controller.stream;
}
```

You can use this the specify `stringGenerator` as:

```dart
Stream<String> stringGenerator(List<http.Request> requests) async* {
  var client = http.Client();
  yield* fromFutures(requests.map(client.send));
}
```